# AWS SDK not including Access Key (AKID) in X-Amz-Credential when creating presigned post, but only on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ruby

I am doing a direct to S3 upload, and I have the presigned post declared like this:

```
@s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "images/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', allow_any: ['utf8', 'authenticity_token'])
```

When in the development environment, it builds everything correctly and I get something like this:

```
{"key"=>"images/1be59d13-9d65-4d70-b631-93834409f361/${filename}", "success_action_status"=>"201", "acl"=>"public-read", "policy"=>"<BASE_64_POLICY>", "x-amz-credential"=>"<MY_ACCESS_KEY>/20180505/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request", "x-amz-algorithm"=>"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256", "x-amz-date"=>"20180505T232823Z", "x-amz-signature"=>"<AMZ_SIGNATURE>"}
```

But after I push it to Heroku, I get something like this:

```
{"key"=>"images/1be59d13-9d65-4d70-b631-93834409f361/${filename}", "success_action_status"=>"201", "acl"=>"public-read", "policy"=>"<BASE_64_POLICY>", "x-amz-credential"=>"/20180505/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request", "x-amz-algorithm"=>"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256", "x-amz-date"=>"20180505T232823Z", "x-amz-signature"=>"<AMZ_SIGNATURE>"}
```

Now that my Access Key (AKID) is no longer there, I get this error:

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>a non-empty Access Key (AKID) must be provided in the credential.</Message><ArgumentName>X-Amz-Credential</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>/20180505/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request</ArgumentValue><RequestId>%REQUESTID%</RequestId><HostId>%HOSTID%</HostId></Error>
```

My AWS credentials are declared in initalizers/aws.rb, so they are not dependent on the environment type. What could possibly be causing this?

Edit (showing how I declare the S3_BUCKET is a constant I initialize in aws.rb):

`Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])
})`

`S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])`

Also, the difference between the two presigned-post objects:

`"x-amz-credential"=>"<MY_ACCESS_KEY>/20180505/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"`

`"x-amz-credential"=>"/20180505/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not commit your credentials in your git repository so you should make sure in your initializer:

in config/initializers/credentials.rb

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
```

And use heroku-cli to configure your credentials on your app

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=someLongHashKey AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=anotherLongHashKey --app my_app_name
# see heroku config --help
```

But your error may have to do with [AWS SDK Presigned Post Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731386/aws-sdk-presigned-post-ruby#31731573)

and see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/PresignedPost.html

If that doesn't help, post how you're defining  `Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new`

Finally, double check to make sure you've set your environment variables correctly in heroku

```
heroku config --app my_app_name #use your actual app name of course
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just updated OP to show how I declare S3_BUCKET using environment variables, but the issue is `Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new` giving me different answers in development and production when the environment variables are the same. The first line of code in OP is how I define `Aws::S3::PresignedPost.new`, using the S3_BUCKET constant I defined in aws.rb. Development gives me a correct presigned-post, and production gives me a presigned-post without an access key at the beginning of x-amz-credential. I can't find any documentation about why this would happen.

Comment: are you sure you've set the environment variables in Heroku?  if you type this in the command line `heroku config --app my_app_name` it should output all of your environment variables.  Make sure those are set correctly and don't contain any typos.

Comment: _**sigh**_ It was a typo in my heroku environment variable. I thought I had double checked that but apparently not well enough. Thanks for the help!